# Is it possible to create a fully customised keyboard for iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I want to do a customised keyboard. Either
1. Create a view with all the buttons similar to default keyboard present but with some changes in the controls.
                                            OR
2. Is it possible to change the color of already present keyboard or its alphabets/numbers.

Is it possible to do either of them? Is there anything similar to this?

Comment: visit the following link may be you get your answer. [keyboard](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, and it's not difficult. In iOS versions 3.2 and greater, you can set the [`inputView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputView) property for any responder. When that responder becomes first responder, the input view will be displayed.